# Matplotlib/Seaborn - grouping bar chart for multiple values/columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to do something fairly simple but having trouble grouping the columns as I want. Here's my dataframe-

```
  food_form  protein   fat  carb
0     food1     28.9  15.6  50.0
1     food2     47.1  33.1  15.3
```

I want to plot this dataframe in one figure, comparing each nutrient against eachother for food1 and food2. So food1 and food2 will be my "hue"  but I want the "X" values of Protein, Fat, and Carb with their corresponding Y values being bar charts. I want the Protein of food 1 plotted right next to Protein of food 2, etc.

By doing `avg_df.plot.bar(x='food_form')` I'm able to come up with the below but it uses the X labels as the food_form which isn't quite what I want.

[image]

Comment: Would `avg_df.T.plot.bar()` be what you're after?

Comment: When I try that it gives me an error - "Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"

Comment: Maybe `df.set_index('food_form').T.plot.bar()`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes that did the trick, thank you! If you want to put that solution as an answer I will accept it. Off to study why I didn't think of this, thanks again.

Comment: I would leave it to you to write the answer. Probably you would better know how to word it based on why that solution wasn't obvious in the first place. It might then be more useful for future readers who got stuck at a similar point.